# Set timed status bar notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to activate a notification when I press a button, at certain hour for this example 12:56 so I used this in my code:

```
Button notificationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    notificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Notify("Title: Meeting with Business",
                   "Msg:Pittsburg 10:00 AM EST "));     
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent1);
```

and i created a class named Notify which contains these codes :

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Class<?> Notify(String notificationTitle, String    notificationMessage) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
           Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
             "New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
           notification.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(),   notificationTitle, notificationMessage, null);
        notificationManager.notify();

        return null;
    }
```

after running the app i get this error :

```
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715): Process: com.example.notify, PID: 18715
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at com.example.notify.MainActivity$1.Notify(MainActivity.java:61)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at com.example.notify.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
09-27 12:55:57.836: E/AndroidRuntime(18715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

My final goal is to set notification  for tomorrow, next week and next month, and if you know how to use a method that is not deprecated I'll be very thankful to know, I also didn't have any receiver or implementation in manifest if there is needed such tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the activity with button click event. It will set the alarm with particular time. It will inform the broadcast receiver.

```
Button notificationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

notificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , WakeUpReceiver.class);  
        myIntent.setAction("com.intent.action.MEETING_BUSINESS");
        myIntent.putExtra("Title","Meeting with Business");
        myIntent.putExtra("Message","Pittsburg 10:00 AM EST");

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(YourActivityName.this, 0,  myIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);    

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

The broadcast receiver is actually responsible for firing the notification.

In your Android manifest.xml file add this intent filter and register the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.WakeUpReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.intent.action.MEETING_BUSINESS" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Define the broadcast receiver class:

```
packager com.package;

public class WakeUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action =  intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("com.intent.action.MEETING_BUSINESS")){
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
            String message = intnet.getStringExtra("Message");

            // if you want to open the application when click on notification 
            // then pass the activity name here.
            PendingIntent intent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, intent, 0); //<- pass your activity name here.

            Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(context)//<-- pass the context
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(intent1)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, n); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty, there is some errror one of the is String title = intent.getExtra("Title"); should be intent .getstringextras("title")

Comment: another error is : Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); which is giving me error .i crate a separate class file for wakupreciever.

Comment: and this line says counstructor not defined : Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)

Comment: Says .setContentIntent(intent1) should be pending intent which giving me errros on this line : Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

Comment: Let me know if still face any problem :)

Comment: i edited the code , No errors i also set the clock and press the button but nothing happens even when clock passes the 12.56

Comment: Ohh sorry I made the mistake let me update the answer we sure make it workable.

Comment: @Soheyl: It is not a good style to edit the code of another person directly. The usual way is to ask the other person to modify their code if you find any issues with their code.

Comment: @honk ok i will ask for edit next time , sorry .and most of my edit was type mismatches .

Comment: I see the problem is PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

Comment: We did not register service we had create the broadcast receiver. We must use pending intent with broadcast receiver :)

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Comment: Now I think the broadcast receive sure update you let's check it I am sure it will work.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar The method getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity.WakeUpReceiver, int, Intent, int)

Comment: What it means? I did not get you.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar oh sorry i changed the pending intent in wakupreciever instead of my onclick pending intent now i'm fixed it but there is error in intent part of it this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT it says : intent is not resolved to variable and the options are to change it to getintent or change it to myintetn, and when i change it to myintent i get this error on .getbroadcast :The method getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, Intent, int)

Comment: update it let's check it you have to pass your activity.this instead of this.

Comment: This is the signature of : "public static PendingIntent getBroadcast(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90731/discussion-between-soheyl-and-bhavdip-pathar).

Answer (score 0):

try to make a notification like this:

```
Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notIntent, 0);

Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Contenttitle")
        .setContentText("Contenttext")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallicon)
        .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .addAction(R.drawable.smallicon, "Call", pendIntent).build();


NotificationManager notManager = 
  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notManager.notify(0, n);
```